# Superview seems to clip subviews using Auto Layout in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, autolayout

I have a view that contains many other subviews. It contains a UIWebView with a dynamic height and a few views vertically pinned to each other about 10px a part.

I'm attempting to set the super view's constraint (detailsContainer) like so:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.detailsContainerView
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:nil
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                  constant:9000];
heightConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityRequired;
[self.detailsContainerView addConstraint:heightConstraint];
```

However, despite everything else being positioned correctly, it appears that it's not resizing properly (using 9000 as an experiment here). For some reason the subviews get cut off (clipToBounds is set to NO).

I think that there may be something else changing the height of this view (though, I don't see any breaking constraints in the debugger).

Here's a trace

```
[[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]

*<UIWindow:0xcd9fd90> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
    |   *<UILayoutContainerView:0x133834c0>
    |   |   *<UINavigationTransitionView:0x133847c0>
    |   |   |   *<UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x14597730>
    |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x1339dbc0>
    |   |   |   |   |   *<UIScrollView:0x1339ce20>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   *<PNDetailsContainerView:0x1339c9f0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<PNProductDetailsContent:0x1339c5c0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x133bb8b0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIScrollView:0x133a4be0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x133a4db0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <_UIPageViewControllerContentView:0xcb408f0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <_UIQueuingScrollView:0x122a4a00>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x10e88720>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x10e887d0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0xcb406a0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0x10e81870>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x10e88860>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0x133a51f0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0x133a5390>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<PNDetailsContainerView:0x133b5100>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x133b52f0> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x133b5380>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x133b5af0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x133b5e10>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x133b65b0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIImageView:0x13350be0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIPageControl:0x133b7550>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x145a3610>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x145a3830>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x145a3a30>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x10e890a0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<PNDescriptionWebView:0x133a7410>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <_UIWebViewScrollView:0x133af740>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIWebBrowserView:0xd3fc800>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x133bab70> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x133bad40>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIImageView:0x133bb0e0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x133a18b0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0x133a1a70>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0xe85dd80>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UITextView:0xd3dec00>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <_UITextContainerView:0x133c7ce0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0x133bbd90>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0x133bbf60>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x133a4200> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIScrollView:0x133a4290>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<PNColorSizeButton:0x144c3b00> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x144c3bf0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<PNColorSizeButton:0x144c4f20> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x144c5010>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<PNColorSizeButton:0x144c6330> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x144c6420>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<PNColorSizeButton:0x144c7720> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x144c7810>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<PNColorSizeButton:0x144c8b10> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x144c8c00>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIScrollView:0x133a3ca0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<PNColorSizeButton:0xe8445b0> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0xe844850>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<PNColorSizeButton:0xe84a290> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0xe84a380>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<PNColorSizeButton:0xe84f7d0> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0xe84f8c0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x133a35a0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0xe85bcf0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0x133a37b0> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x133a13d0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0xe85ae50>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x133a2f40>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0xe859ce0>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0x145975a0>
    |   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0x1339dc50>
    |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0xe858c70>
    |   |   |   |   |   *<_UILayoutGuide:0x1339e720> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
    |   |   |   |   |   *<_UILayoutGuide:0x1339ec50> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
    |   |   <UINavigationBar:0x10b524b0>
    |   |   |   <_UINavigationBarBackground:0xe9bcad0>
    |   |   |   |   <_UIBackdropView:0x133835d0>
    |   |   |   |   |   <_UIBackdropEffectView:0x133839d0>
    |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0x13383a70>
    |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0xe9bcbb0>
    |   |   |   <UINavigationItemView:0x10b52c90>
    |   |   |   |   <UILabel:0x10b52d40>
    |   |   |   <UINavigationButton:0xbf0b790>
    |   |   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0xbf0b490>
    |   |   |   <UINavigationButton:0xbf0a370>
    |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0xbf09d10>
    |   |   |   <_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView:0x133983e0>
```

I'd love to solve this one so the detailsContainerView is the actual size.

Might be important to note that this entire view is being loaded as a subview into another view that belongs to a scroll view. I can manually set the contentSize as well as the view's height, just the detailViewController doesn't seem to want to take the 9000 height (or perhaps something else is the culprit).